# How to convert exact Latitude and Longitude coordinates to X,Y coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a world map drawn in a canvas using Java script. How can I convert the exact **latitude,longitude** coordinates of any place into **X,Y** coordinates so that I can project those converted X,Y coordinates on my Canvas Map?

I have tried different solutions provided earlier, but they are not pointing to **exact** X,Y coordinates on my Canvas Map. Also I have tried using basic conversion formulas, but they haven't been useful as well. 
For example,

```
var y = ((-1 * lat) + 90) * (MAP_HEIGHT / 180);
var x = (lon + 180) * (MAP_WIDTH / 360);
```

OR

```
function plot_point(lat, lng) {
// longitude_shift = number of pixels your map's prime meridian is off-center.
// Mercator projection

// longitude: just scale and shift
x = (map_width * (180 + lng) / 360) % map_width + longitude_shift;

// latitude: using the Mercator projection
lat = lat * Math.PI / 180;  // convert from degrees to radians
y = Math.log(Math.tan((lat/2) + (Math.PI/4))); 
y = (map_height / 2) - (map_width * y / (2 * Math.PI)) + y_pos;
```

I am using the following map : [Map](http://cs.wellesley.edu/~tanner10/world-maps/world-map-background.jpg)

P.S. If anybody can provide a **Java script** code, that would be very helpful.

**EDIT** Since I cannot obtain exact coordinates, thanks to explanation of 
@Aki Suihkonen, please suggest a method so that I can get X,Y coordinates nearest to its true location in the map. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us some examples of what you have tried, that way we might be able to see where you are getting stuck.

Comment: It's impossible, unless the world map follows some known _geodetic datum_ and is provided with exact information how it's projected. You can't expect a random conceptual map to provide accurate scientific data about "true" positions, which are subject to complex models of 3-dimensional reality.

Comment: "exact latitude,longitude" and `parseInt`? Whole degree is approximately 110 km.

Comment: Ok, if not exact, I at least want to project the coordinates nearly true to its location. Also what if I want equi-rectangular projections?

Comment: @Igor Please Ignore parseInt, and focus on lng variable. I was just trying some modifications. I have reverted back to lng variable.

Comment: Google Maps allows you to do this using the projection layer, but if you're using a proprietary map, read Aki's comment above.